# Create New Dict from Existing DIct Using List of Values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of values and want to create a new dictionary from an existing dictionary using the key/value pairs that correspond to the values in the list. I can't find a Stackoverflow answer that covers this.

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

original_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 9, "d": 2, "e": 6, "f": 1}

desired_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 2, "f": 1}
```

Note that there are some values that are assigned to multiple keys in `original_dict` (as in the example).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dict comprehension`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) or you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter).

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

original_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 9, "d": 2, "e": 6, "f": 1}

desired_dict = {key: value for key, value in original_dict.items() if value in example_list}

# Option_2
desired_dict = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] in example_list, original_dict.items()))
# -------------------------------^^^ x[0] is key, x[1] is value of 'dict'

print(desired_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 2, 'f': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `original_dict.items()` to `filter` and then the results of `filter` can be recast to `dict`.

```
el = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

od = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 9, "d": 2, "e": 6, "f": 1}

# `i` will be (key,value)
dd = dict(filter(lambda i: i[1] in el, od.items()))

print(dd) #{"a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 2, "f": 1}
```